# About the performance of a model after changing the class attribute

Tags: binary-data, unbalanced-classes, overfitting

I want to build a model using a dataset. Then, I edit the dataset by changing the class attribute (let's say I will have a new version of the dataset). After that, I want to apply the same model to the new version of the dataset.

Is this procedure correct?
Because I did it but the performance of the model improved significantly.

I will explain my procedure in detailed steps:

1. I have an imbalanced binary classification dataset (let's call it: a raw dataset).
2. I balanced the raw dataset using SMOTE technique.
3. I built a model and its performance was: accuracy (86.4626), precision (84.7), recall (86.5), F1-measure (84.5), and AUC-ROC (80.9).
4. I changed the class attribute of the raw dataset (let's say I had a new imbalanced dataset).
5. I balanced the new dataset using SMOTE technique.
6. I applied the same model, mentioned in step 3, to the new dataset, and its performance was: accuracy (96.9388), precision (97.6), recall (96.9), F1-measure (97.1), and AUC-ROC (99).

I'm afraid there is something wrong with what I did causing overfitting or something.